# Is there a way to read the usage history of BBC news app in Android?

Tags: android, history

In my project I need to access the history of usage(news read by the user) of a news app like BBC news. Does the BBC news or any other news app save the history of news which were read by the user in some file or format? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to read the RSS feeds From bbc news

Comment: @Nate No, I want to read those links (news items) which the user viewed (clicked on) in the past. I hope that clarifies the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the BBC news or any other news app save the history of news which were read by the user in some file or format?

I hope they do not in any publicly readable fashion, for obvious privacy and security reasons.